# Flashvideo in Firefox addon panel only plays sound

Tags: flash, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a Firefox addon with a panel. In this panel I have embedcode for a flashvideo. When I click on it to start playback I only get sound and no video.

Does anyone have any idea why or any pointers to further investigate?

Answer (score 0):

I also created a firefox addon, that get the current video link of activeTab, and I have the same problem.

No video display on addon's Panel, but when I click on the video's square area, there's sound but no video.

Updated on Nov 12th, 2012.

Till now, AddOnSDK is 1.11, and this issue is still there. The issue is getting more severe because it make Firefox v16 stop working and need to be restart.